# rake aborted! undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "adapter:postgresql host:localhost database:mailerDevelopment":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

If I run rake db:migrate I get the following error:
rake aborted!
undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "adapter:postgresql host:localhost database:mailerDevelopment":String

The development entry in my database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter:postgresql
  host:localhost
  database:mailerDevelopment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because the content of the database.yml file is **not valid YAML**.

In YAML the space after separators like `:` is mandatory. **Reference:** [Collections section in the YAML documentation](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726)

So change the content of the file as follows (with spaces after the `:`):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: mailerDevelopment
```

Comment: That was it and I'd like to point out that tabs also cause errors.